# Appending to variable in Makefiles for HP-UX make

Tags: makefile, hp-ux

I'm trying to append some text to a variable in a Makefile for HP-UX's version of make.

If i use the "normal" appender, like this:

```
CFLAGS+=some text
```

$(CFLAGS) comes out empty.

If i reference the variable, like this:

```
CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) some text
```

make complains about "infinitely recursive macro."

Using a temporary variable like this:

```
CFLAGStmp=$(CFLAGS)
CFLAGS=$(CFLAGStmp) some text
```

also complains about an "infinitely recursive macro."

How can i append something to a variable in HP-UX make's Makefile?

Comment: I don't have access to HP-Make, so I can't experiment, but I'd try 1) fiddling with the whitespace, 2) using simple assignment := if HP-make allows it, or best of all 3) switching to GNUmake

Comment: @Beta 1) Does not help. 2) Syntax error. 3) Not the ideal solution, but might be only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that the only solution to this problem is to use [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (gmake).

Example:

```
$ cat >Makefile
FOO=bar
FOO+=baz

all:
    @echo $(FOO)
^D
$ make
bar baz
```

Comment: It seems that I am running GNU Make 3.81. How is this possible using GNU Make?